# Dirichlet series decomposition of arbitrary function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

Originally asked on MSE here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780149/52694

Analytic functions can be decomposed into a Taylor series, and furthermore the Taylor series converges back to the original function at every point.

Is there a corresponding notion for Dirichlet series? When is a function able to be decomposed into a Dirichlet series, and does a decomposition exist for any common functions?

To clarify, by Dirichlet series I mean a decomposition of a function $f(s)$ into the form

$f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$

for complex $s$ and some complex sequence of $a_n$.

Comment: This seems to address your questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30975/dirichlet-series-expansion-of-an-analytic-function?rq=1

Comment: You have to define exactly what you mean by Dirichlet series: this word can have several different meanings. What are your exponents? Real? Complex? $\log n$?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a "classic" Dirichlet series, for lack of a better term. So $\log n$.

Comment: Functions that can be expanded into a classical Dirichlet series make a very special class, for example they are bounded on every vertical line where the series is absolutely convergent, they are almost periodic on these lines, with prescribed spectrum, etc.