# An analytic function, asymptotically expandable in a Dirichlet series, is the sum of this series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, dirichlet-series, analytic-functions

Let there be a function $F(s)$ that is analytic in some half-plane $\sigma>\sigma_0$ (where $s=\sigma + it $). Let the function $F(s)$ have an asymptotic expansion of the form $F(s)\sim\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{a (n)} {n ^ s} $, valid for $\sigma\to + \infty $. It seems to me that I have proved that under such conditions the function $ F (s) $ in some half-plane $ \sigma> \sigma_1 $ can be represented by the converging Dirichlet series $ F (s) = \sum \limits_{n = 1} ^ \infty \frac {a (n)} {n ^ s} $. Is this a known result? If so, is there a generalization of it to the general Dirichlet series $ \sum \limits_ {n = 1} ^ \infty a_n e ^ {- \lambda_n s} $? As far as I know, without the conditions on $\{ \lambda_n \}$, the statement is not true.
I would be grateful for the literary links.

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: If $F(s)=\sum_{n<k} a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}+O(e^{-\lambda_k s})$ as $\Re(s) \to\infty$  then shifting the contour to the right gives that for $u<\lambda_k$: $\displaystyle\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{r-i\infty}^{r+i\infty}\frac{F(s)}{s^2}e^{su} ds=\int_{-\infty}^u \sum_{\lambda_n < v} a_n dv$ from which $\frac{F(s)}{s}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\sum_{u\le \lambda_n} a_n) e^{-su}du$ (for $\Re(s)>r>\sigma_0>0)$.

Comment: You'd like some condition to avoid $\sum_{u\le \lambda_n} a_n$ being an approximation of things like $e^{u^2} \sin(e^{e^u})1_{u>0}$ which would give $\frac{F(s)}{s}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\sum_{u\le \lambda_n} a_n) e^{-su}du$ well-defined but with $\sum_n a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}$ divergent (when not grouping the terms correctly). A sufficient condition for $\sum_n a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}$ to converge is $\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n$ bounded below.